# Comparing Amount in Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms, angular-forms

I need to compare the `amount` from the `applied_amount`. However they are on different controls but they are on the same formgroup. How should i check if the "amount" is greater than the "applied_amount"? Here's the code below.

```
 this.reportForm = this.fb.group({
                employee_id: [null, Validators.required],
                outlet_id: [null, Validators.required],
                grand_total: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
                rows: this.fb.array([]),
                applied_amount: [null, Validators.required],
            });


initGroup() {
        let rows = this.reportForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
        rows.push(this.fb.group({
            expense_account: ['', Validators.required],
            description: ['', Validators.required],
            amount: ['', Validators.required],
        },{validator: this.customValidator(rows)}))
    }



customValidator(group: any) {
        if ((group.controls.amount.value > group.parent.parent.controls.applied_amount.value)) {
            return { out1: true }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @BorisLobanov. I dont know how to compare the “applied_amount” from “amount”. I should compare if “amount” is greater than “applied_amount”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't call method `customValidator` method as mentioned @Boris Lobanov

> It says it cannot read parent of undefined

That is because when angular creates `FormGroup` through `FormBuilder::group` it also calls validators but current group doesn't have parent yet. The parent will be set only after `FormArray::push`.

So the solution could look like:

```typescript
validator: this.customValidator
...

customValidator(group: any) {
  if (!group.parent ) {
      return;
  }
  ...
```

I also fire validation for all rows when `applied_amount` is changed.

html

```typescript
<input type="number" formControlName="applied_amount" (ngModelChange)="validateAllRows()">
```

ts

```typescript
validateAllRows() {
  const rows = this.reportForm.get('rows') as FormArray;

  rows.controls.forEach(group => {
    group.updateValueAndValidity();
  })
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/O0sFq1CmP2ChVUJbdEvy)**

Another solution is almost the same like yours:

```typescript
validator: this.customValidator.bind(rows)
...

customValidator(this: FormArray, group: any) {
  if (group.controls.amount.value > this.parent.controls['applied_amount'].value) {
    return { out1: true }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Here I use `Function.prototype.bind` method to pass `FormArray` directly to your validator.

Comment: Thanks yurzui. But when my problem is when there are several rows of "amount". How would i check if their "amount" is not more than the "applied_amount"?

Comment: Yes i did. But i can't save your demo.

Comment: I will check it later

Comment: Here it is. https://ng-run.com/edit/qXxjMdvGKqn9UkA0RQw3?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: first. i type 1000 in the applied_amount. Then on the first amount, i type 500, then on the second amount, i type 510. It should output an error.

Comment: But your validator only checks value of current group. You need to sum all values instead

Comment: Yes that's my problem. How would i do it? I also don't want to show the total? I can achieve this BUT i don't want to show the total amount.

Comment: You miss something. Why if i type 1000 in the applied_amount. And then i type 999 in the first input and 2 in the second input. It outputs an error. BUT the problem arises, when i go back to the first input and change 999 to 998. The group valid should be true, how come it is still false?

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem arises, when i go back to the first input and change 999 to 998. The group valid should be true, how come it is still false

Comment: It's the same case as I wrote in my answer `I also fire validation for all rows when applied_amount is changed.` Each form doesn't know anything about other

Comment: It means that you missed something. Check this update https://ng-run.com/edit/Vhvk0iGIJEWI4OXeCcNW

Comment: Hi. I implemented this in my local project and it has error called Expression changed after it was checked error. So i implement the changeDetector ref and the error disappeared. But some says the changedetectorref is not good since it is an expensive operation

Comment: Hello are you there?

Comment: Omg.. I dont know why I need to waste so much time on stackoverflow. Whats wrong with my answet? If it doesn't work you should at least provide reproduction. ChangeDetectorRef  can be used to fix Expression has changed.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to hear. Thanks yurzui

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are passing the FormArray (rows) into the validator rather than the group.

I suggest rewriting it like so:

```
initGroup() {
   let rows = this.reportForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
   rows.push(this.fb.group({
       expense_account: ['', Validators.required],
       description: ['', Validators.required],
       amount: ['', Validators.required],
   },{validator: this.customValidator})) // it will automatically be applied to the group
}
```

Comment: I think i have a problem with the customValidator. It says it cannot read parent of undefined. I need to check whether the "amount" is more than the  "applied_amount". The "amount" is inside the rows, while the "applied_amount" is outside the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom validator.  demo here---> [validator demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x86t3z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvalidator.component.ts)

```
 form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        high: [null, Validators.required],
        low: [null, Validators.required]
      },
      {
        validator: LowHighValidation
      }
    );
  }


const LowHighValidation: ValidatorFn = (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
  console.log(formGroup);
  const low = formGroup.get("low").value;
  const high = formGroup.get("high").value;
  let validation = null;
  if (low !== null && high !== null && low < high) {
    validation = {
      validation: true
    };
  }
  return validation;
};
```